# Selecionar checkboxes que vem do banco no form de edição

Tags: php, mysql, html5, bootstrap-3

Olá, eu tenho um form de edição de usuário que tem algumas chekbox com nomes de cidades que devem estar selecionadas quando o form for aberto. Pois bem, estou selecionando no banco as cidades para as quais o usuário que está sendo editado tem acesso e fazendo uma comparação na tag **`<input>`** para imprimir 'checked' caso a comparação seja verdadeira. Acontece que a query só me retorna o primeiro registro do banco no array e os outros não. Alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando, por favor? Agradeço desde já. Código e mais informações abaixo:

[image: O sistema só exibe uma checckbox selecionada mesmo o banco retornando mais de uma]

[Tive dificuldade postar o código diretamente então pus no pastebin. Espero que não seja um incômodo.](http://pastebin.com/jQHDuJBP)

```
    {   <?php
   include_once ('../dao/usuario_dao.php');

   $id = $_GET['id_usuario'];

   //Dados do usuário
   $resultado = sel_usuario($id);
   $reg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

   //Dados das regionais para as quais o usuário tem acesso
   $resultado2 = sel_regionais_usuario($id);
   $regional = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);

   //var_dump($regional['id']);

?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> EDITAR USUÁRIO
        </div><br>

        <div id="filtros" style="padding-left: 20px">
            <a id="voltar_pagina" href="menu.php" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar ao início">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </a>
            <a id="voltar_lista" href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
            </a>                        
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <form id="form_cad_usuario" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="../config/usuario/processa_cad_usuario.php">

                <!--DADOS DO USUÁRIO-->
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h4>Dados do Usuário</h4s>
                    <hr>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">                
                    <label for="status_check" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ativo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input id="status_check" name="status_check" type="checkbox" value="ativo" checked>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input
                           type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_usuario"
                           name="nome_usuario" placeholder="Nome"
                           data-error="Por favor, informe o nome completo para o usuário." required
                           value="<?php echo $reg['nome']; ?>"
                        >
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--DADOS DE ACESSO-->
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h4>Dados de Acesso</h4>
                    <hr>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="login_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuário</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input
                           type="text" class="form-control" id="login_usuario"
                           name="login_usuario" placeholder="Usuário"
                           data-error="Por favor, informe o nome de usuário que será usado no login."
                           required
                           value="<?php echo $reg['login']; ?>"
                        >
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="permissao_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Permissão</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="permissao_usuario" name="permissao_usuario" data-error="Por favor, selecione um nível de permissão para o usuário." required>
                            <option value="4">Jogos</option>
                            <option value="3">Regional</option>
                            <option value="2">Administrador</option>
                            <option value="1">Master</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--DADOS DA  REGIONAL-->
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h4>Regionais Permitidas</h4>
                    <hr>
                </div>

                <?php
               $resultado = lista_regionais();

               while($reg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
               {
                   $id_regional = $reg['id'];
                   $nome_regional = $reg['nome'];

                   //var_dump($id_regional);
               ?>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <label class="col-md-10" for="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>">
                                        <input
                                           type="checkbox" name="<?php echo"regional[$id_regional]"; ?>"
                                            id="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>"
                                            value="<?php echo $nome_regional; ?>"
                                            <?php
                                               if($id_regional == $regional['id'])
                                               {
                                                   echo 'checked';
                                               }
                                           ?>
                                        >    
                                        <small><?php echo $nome_regional; ?></small>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
               }
               ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button id="botao_salvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Salvar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

Ahh! E se tiver um jeito mais eficiente de tratar esses dados para mostra-los no form eu agradeço a dica. Abraço!

Comment: Na hora de fazer a comparação vc precisa de um foreach para comparar `$regional` com `$id_regional`

Comment: Mesmo o vardump do atrás que vem do banco só retornando um elemento? Poderia mostrar o código, por favor?

Comment: Consegui resolver baseado na tua dica.Obrigado, cara.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, vou deixar o código aqui caso seja de interesse de outra pessoa. Segue o código php que usei dentro do  que gera as checkboxes.

```
<input 
                                        type="checkbox" name="<?php echo"regional[$id_regional]"; ?>" 
                                        id="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>" 
                                        value="<?php echo $nome_regional; ?>"
                                        <?php
                                            $resultado2 = sel_regionais_usuario($id);
                                            while($reg_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2))
                                            {
                                                if($reg_usuario['id'] == $id_regional)
                                                {
                                                    echo 'checked';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    >
```